# Coordinate transformations for systems of differential equations, the number of which $ \geq 3.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

It is known that for systems of $2$ differential equations you can make transformations from Cartesian to polar coordinates, for example:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45339/polar-differential-equation

And what transformations exist for systems of differential equations, the number of which is equal to or exceeds $3?$

Comment: There are cylindrical or spherical for n=3.

Comment: @user376343, And for a larger dimension, >3 for example?

Comment: @user376343, Interestingly, such coordinates even exist?

Comment: Spherical/cylindrical coordinates generalize to arbitrary dimension; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates).

Comment: @Kajelad, Thank you very much.